# List of substring or regex match in a field in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i have a document

```
{title: 'India is my country'}
```

i need to find and return this document when any elements in list contain in title field

```
list = ["when","is","and"]
```

How can i return this in pymongo find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to generate a regular expression containing all the items in the list ( that should do good if the list is not large).
But if the list is large, you shall query for each item seperately.
Regex would be used in both the cases.

```
import re
term_list = ["when","is","and"]
regexp = re.compile(r"|".join(term_list), re.IGNORECASE)
db.my_collection.find_one({"title": regexp })
```

Comment: thanks,also please query for document not in that list